# Cocos2d Lua Latest Version

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, lua

I am going through a major crisis here and i would like to ask for advices.
I have been developing a game the last couple of months which is entirely based on lua scripting. The project is a cocos2d based project with the inclusion of the mclua library (more about mcLua can be found here http://www.grzmobile.com/blog/2009/12/1/integrating-lua-into-and-iphone-app-part-2.html).

Now i am nearly at the end of the implementation of the project and i just found out that apparently the version of lua that i use which is 5.1.4 does not have a goto statement which is of great importance to this project. The latest version of lua 5.2 however supports now goto statements.

My problem is that when i tried to add the lua version 5.2 to my project the library mclua throws a bunch of errors and it seems that this library doesn’t work with any other version of lua other than 5.1.4.

What can i do about this now? I was supposed to be nearly at completion of the project. Does this mean i am completely screwed now ?

Comment: Kind of odd that you're close to finishing the project and NOW you realize there's no goto and that's somehow very important. If you got this far you DON'T need goto. Programmers have been using Lua for nearly 20 years without goto. I side with Nicol's answer here. You can always rewrite code not to use goto (although usually with more lines of code).

Answer (score 0):

Then you have a choice to make. You may:

1. Stop doing whatever makse `goto` "of great importance to this project". I've used Lua for a while and I've never *needed* `goto` that badly. Whatever you're doing can be done in some other way.
2. Modify this "mclua" library to fix the "bunch of errors" you get when you try to link it against Lua 5.2. Since you didn't explain what these errors are, we can't really help you in solving them.

Note that Lua's minor version numbers are not intended to guarantee backwards compatibile with prior versions. While the changes are generally relatively small, that doesn't mean that effort was extended to make code work in both without modification.